# Filtering the ICMP packets on Solaris using IP-addresses from the table

Tags: solaris, pf, icmp

I'm currently working with Packet Filter on Solaris machine, trying to create a rule that would filter out all ICMP packets of particular type and code. Here is my rule line:

```
block out quick proto icmp from any to <MY_TABLE_34> icmp-type 3 code 1
```

I'm getting the error "must indicate address family with icmp-type/code". Does it mean that I can't use tables in rules that specify ICMP types and codes? If that's the case then is there a better way than just write a separate rule for each address in the table?

OS: Solaris 11.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `block out quick proto icmp from any …`
>
> …
>
> "must indicate address family with icmp-type/code".

Common types of address families supported by Pf are `inet`/`inet6`, should be written that way therefore:

block out quick **inet** proto icmp from any …